# use on/off key in smarty templates

Tags: forms, smarty, javascript

I want to know how can I use on/off(disable/enable) in my smarty template for disable or enable the options.
For example I have a form to receive text from users and I want to do this: if user uses enable he can input text and if he uses disable, forms will become off and he won't be able to input text.
Is it possible with javascript? how? and my template engine is smarty.
TNX

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" />
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: So.. you want to disable it with javascript or smarty?

Comment: @Borgtex : my template is smarty.

Comment: @Borgtex:Can i use java scripts in smarty?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is just to use [if statements in Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl).

i.e. assign a variable `showForm` in PHP and then in Smarty you can turn the form on or off:

```
{if isset($showForm) && $showForm)
   <form action="">
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" />
   <button type="submit"></button>
   </form>
{/if}
```